# How is each column of natural spline calculated?

Tags: r, spline, non-linear-regression

If I run the code below, I will get a spline object with 4 columns.

```
library(splines) 

x <- seq(0, 1, length.out = 11)

ns(x,df=4)
```

Could you help me understand how each column(for example, column 1, 0.00, 0.01066, 0.08533....) is calculated?

I did some searching and found that the number of columns(4) is related to the number of knots in the natural spline as each trajectory needs a column. However, I didn't find any material mentioning how each column is calculated.

Comment: Are you looking for a tutorial on splines? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-spline  If you look for the help at `?ns`, it says it makes a B-spline basis matrix for a natural cubic spline, and it is based on the function `splineDesign`. There is another help page for `splineDesign`, and you can ctrl-click `splineDesign` in the script window to see its underlying source code.